# Java heap memory usage increases

Tags: java, heap-memory, jconsole

I was doing a quick experiment to see how my algorithm's memory performance looks like. 
The input is about 2 Mb and the algorithm takes about 1 second to run it.
I ran this in a loop for 500 times to be able to look at the memory allocation.

This is how jConsole shows the memory usage:

[image]

As you can see heap memory usage increases (kinda exponentially) every two times before GC starts (even though the input is the same).

Does anybody know if this is expected and why it happens? Is it some optimization done by JVM?

Thanks!

Comment: Read http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19900-01/819-4742/abeik/index.html

Comment: it seems like your algorithm takes more time to run. Are you sure you are running the same number of iterates?

Comment: @JigarJoshi if you look at the memory after a GC, you can see there isn't a memory leak (at least not a big one)

Comment: I agree -- not sign of a memory leak.

Comment: You cannot tell if that is expected without knowing the algorithm.

Answer (score 3):

> Does anybody know if this is expected and why it happens? Is it some optimization done by JVM?

The JVM is trying to minimise the time spent GC-ing.  If you use more memory, it doesn't have to GC as often.

> a leak?

If you look at memory usage after a GC it is much the same so clearly it doesn't have a memory leak. Or at least not a big one.

You have to look at the memory used after Full GCs to confirm there is a memory leak and I assume these are minor collections.

Comment: you are right, however same data set on different iteration of same algorithm causes the memory to spike up looks suspicious +1

Comment: @JigarJoshi the JVM will progressively change the GC parameters. It tried not to change them too suddenly so a geometric increase is not so surprising. find it can be increased, doubles it, find it can be increased, doubles it etc.

Comment: Thanks Peter. That makes sense and exactly match what's going on here. Also I have used YourKit and confirmed that there is no memory leak. Just a lot of HashMap objects being created.

BTW can you explain (or point me to a documentation) about how GC parameters are tuned? Why is it that "using more memory => GC less often"?

Comment: @N3da You are allocating garbage at a particular rate. say 400 MB/s.  if you have a 400 MB eden space it will GC every second because that is how long you take to fill it. 400 MB / 400 MB/s = 1 s.  If you have a  4 GB heap, it will GC every 10 seconds, 4000 MB / 400 MB/s = 10 s.